# How to mock window.location.search?

Tags: javascript, window.location

I am trying to grab params from a url, but I can't tell if it's working because `console.log(window.location.search)` on localhost:3000 gives me `<empty string>` as a value .

I have tried mocking it like this, but it doesn't return the same thing as `window.location.search`

```
const url = 'https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=query+string

const queryString = url.search

console.log(queryString)  // function search()
```

Is there a way to mock the behavior of window.location.search locally so I can make sure I am getting the data I need before the app is deployed?

Comment: If `window.location.search` is empty, then there's no search string in the URL. You've to navigate to the page using the search string, if you're just writing it to the addressbar without actual navigation, it's not added to `window.location.search`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) object like so:

```
const url = new URL('https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=query+string');

const queryString = url.search

console.log(queryString)  // '?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=query+string'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a function that parse the text to URL then your code will work

```js
function parseURL(url) {
    var parser = document.createElement('a'),
        searchObject = {},
        queries, split, i;
    // Let the browser do the work
    parser.href = url;
    // Convert query string to object
    queries = parser.search.replace(/^\?/, '').split('&');
    for( i = 0; i < queries.length; i++ ) {
        split = queries[i].split('=');
        searchObject[split[0]] = split[1];
    }
    return {
        protocol: parser.protocol,
        host: parser.host,
        hostname: parser.hostname,
        port: parser.port,
        pathname: parser.pathname,
        search: parser.search,
        searchObject: searchObject,
        hash: parser.hash
    };
}

const url = parseURL('https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=query+string')
const queryString = url.search
console.log(queryString)  // function search()
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but in the light of @klugjo's answer, this solution may be attempting to re-create the wheel.

Answer (score -1):

const urlcheck = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const querystringVal= urlParams.get('parameter');

Please check this.